# Process that consumes more bandwidth

Tags: linux, networking, ifconfig

When I do an ifconfig I see that my interfaces eth0 RX is about some Gigabytes,  even I did not run any video or audio over the network nor do some peer to peer staff, please all I need is to identify which process consumes bandwidth, is there a tools that help to detect this.

Comment: Those are running totals not current instantaneous totals.

Comment: If you want to see where it's going at the moment, use ntop

Comment: I know ntop, but I need a cli tool

Comment: Ok, you could use nmon

Comment: nmon can return which process or which socket consume a lot of bandwidth ??

Comment: I did not find any option in nmon that do that

Comment: I found that through google. ok, it looks like it doesn't give a per process thing.  Anyway, as I was saying the ipconfig is a number that keeps counting while the machine is on. If you want it to go back to zero... reboot.  There is a network top equivalent for linux top but ntop seems to be web based... hmm...

Comment: I don't need to go back to zero all I need is to trace from where come all this consummation of bandwidth from which socket or which process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a tool named **nethogs** that is a Net top tool grouping bandwidth per process.
and **iftop** tool that display bandwidth usage on an interface by host.

#### References

- [nethogs](http://nethogs.sourceforge.net/)